# Class design for unknown number of type parameters

Tags: c#, .net, class, class-design

I need to design a class that can hold an arbitrary number of types, although I do not know the type and number of these values at design time. For example - I could initialize the class with 2 ints and a long or just 1 int value. I also would like to avoid boxing as far as possible (using an 'object' type). Each type would also have a name, so an internal dictionary that holds the values could look like

```
Dictionary<string,object> nameValues;//Boxing!
```

and the constructor could look like

```
MyClass(params object[] values) { ... }
```

I could construct an instance like this

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass("intVal",3,"doubleVal",3.5,"dateTimeVal",DateTime.Now);
```

Any suggestions on a more efficient design that would avoid boxing as far as possible.

Edit: It should be possible to specify a 'string' value as a parameter also. I had initially mentioned only Value types but that's not the case anymore!

Comment: I don't see how you can accomplish this without using boxing. On the other hand, if you tell us what you want to do, someone might come up with a better solution.

Comment: is there any limit on the value type parameters i.e. 2,3,4,5

Comment: @decyclone Actually I really want to achieve what I stated - to design an efficient container for arbitrary number of value types where each value type has an associated name.

Comment: @Saurabh There is no limit but I wouldn't expect more than 5 at the most!

Comment: You know strings aren't value types, right?

Comment: @Patrick - Yes I know that but you pointed out something I that missed out from my requirements, I could also expect a string value...so using 'ValueType' in the dictionary as suggested by Dean can be ruled out!

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't be scared of a little boxing; unless you've profiled and proven that it is an issue, this is probably the least of your issues. But how about an anon-type:

```
var mc = new { intVal = 3, doubleVal = 3.5, dateTimeVal = DateTime.Now };
```

The only problem is that **outside of this method** the only way to get these values back out is via reflection. Which isn't *necessarily* a problem. But in many ways the `Dictionary<string,object>` is (while more overweight) much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Dictionary<string, ValueType> x = new Dictionary<string, ValueType>();
x.Add("1",1);
x.Add("2", 23.33m);
x.Add("3", new MyStruct());
x.Add("4", new object()); // compile-time error
```

Comment: As pointed out, I just remembered that 'string' values are also acceptable so can't use 'ValueType' in the dictionary.

Comment: strings are not value types, so you cannot

Comment: the type `ValueType` is (perhaps confusingly) boxed.

Answer (score 2):

If you know in advance the possible types, you can use separate Dictionary for each type then you don't need boxing when reading the values back.

For example, using your existing code structure:

```
class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> intValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private Dictionary<string, double> doubleValues = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    private Dictionary<string, DateTime> dateTimeValues = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

    public MyClass(params object[] values)
    {
        if (values.Length % 2 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid values!", "values");
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string key = values[i].ToString();
            object value = values[i + 1];
            if (value is int)
                intValues.Add(key, (int)value);
            else if (value is double)
                doubleValues.Add(key, (double)value);
            else if (value is DateTime)
                dateTimeValues.Add(key, (DateTime)value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be something like below

```
public class ValueHolder
{
    public ValueType[] Values { get; set; }
    public string[] NonValueType { get; set; }
}

public class SomeValueType<T> where T:ValueHolder
{
    Dictionary<string, T> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, T>();


    public SomeValueType(T val,string keyName)
    {
        if(!tempDict.Keys.Contains(keyName))
             tempDict.Add(keyName, val);
    }

}
```

uses

```
        ValueType[] arr = new ValueType[] { 1, 1.1, DateTime.Now };
        ValueHolder vh = new ValueHolder();
        vh.Values = arr;
        vh.NonValueType = new string[] { "temp", "s" };
        SomeValueType<ValueHolder> temp = new SomeValueType<ValueHolder>(vh, "key");
```

Comment: casting to `ValueType` is actually a boxing operation

Comment: @Marc : Thanks Marc for pointing that out : can you please post me a link which explains this actually i were in the wrong assumption till yet

Comment: I don't have a good reference to hand, but it is only when you know the concrete, exact type *at compile time* that it can treat it as a struct. Perhaps simply the fact that `ValueType` is itself a `class` is evidence enough for you; otherwise, just look in the IL for the box operation.

Comment: but this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx is having some anotehr story , i have seen that ValueType is a abstract class in reflector but MSDN link is somewhat contradicting.

Comment: it says that it can be used to **restrict values** to value-types, which is true; it is, however, still boxed. In 2.0 and above it would be preferable to use generics and enforce `T : struct`, since that would then use the "constrained" opcode, and would try to avoid boxing as far as possible. I will annotate MSDN accordingly ;p